# Does postgres optimise repeated expressions?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, postgresql-performance

```sql
select column_1, (column_1 <-> cube(:input)) / (:input <-> cube(0)) difference from table_1
```

for this query, is calculation of `:input <-> cube(0)` repeated for every row?

Also, for

```sql
select calculation(row) from table_1 row where condition(row, calculation(row))
```

is `calculation` repeated in both the `select`, and `where`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the expression will be evaluated multiple times. This is easy to test:

```
test=> \timing
Timing is on.
test=> SELECT pg_sleep(id)
       FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS x(id)
       WHERE pg_sleep(id) IS NOT NULL;
 pg_sleep 
══════════
 
 
 
(3 rows)

Time: 12013.768 ms (00:12.014)
```

If you want to avoid that, use a subquery:

```
test=> SELECT v
       FROM (SELECT pg_sleep(id) AS v
             FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS x(id)) AS t
       WHERE v IS NOT NULL;
 v 
═══
 
 
 
(3 rows)

Time: 6007.817 ms (00:06.008)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution (which could be rewritten as a with-query) is you have to store the entire set of generated values - regardless of whether they're discarded - as opopsed to generating within the where clause with the opportunity to discard if not passing condition

Comment: The subquery is not "stored", it is flattened - look at the `EXPLAIN` output. This syntax just makes it clear to PostgreSQL that you are talking about the same thing both times when you use `v`.